# Secure full where statement when it comes as a string

Tags: c#, where-clause, sql-injection, sanitization

I have the following C# function

```
        SomeFunction(string table, string column, string where) { 
            Sql sql = new Sql("SELECT ");

            // [...] validate table and column values

            sql.Append(column);
            sql.Append(" FROM ");
            sql.Append(table);
            sql.Append(" WHERE ");
            sql.Append(where); // This is the issue
        }
```

As you can see this is awful, I'm dealing with this very old legacy code and changing the function signature and the way the clients use it is just not feasible. What I have to do is secure the 'where' clause. This clause may contain any number of conditions and data types.

I had a bunch of ideas but I don't think they are a good solution, I think this requires a properly written and tested code, but if I do it myself out of the blue it'll probably have holes. Here are some thoughts:

- Splitting the string by char '=' -> what if that's not the condition operator
- Find if string contains semicolons -> the SELECT clause remains vulnerable, and maybe one of the conditions contains that char so it'd give a false positive

If you have any idea/suggestion/pointing in the right direction I will be most grateful.

Comment: Note that the `table` and `column` are *also* attack vectors, unless you're explicitly asserting that they're trusted values.

Comment: Take the [where clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_(SQL)) and read it's whole documentation (what predicates it accepts), and build on that.

Comment: What Adelin says ^^ but expand to the whole SELECT statement. (Because what Marc says ... )

Comment: there are also `in`, `>`, `<`, `like` etc'. Also, different databases might support different things - for instance MySql supports `(col1, col2) in (value1, value2)` while SQL Server will throw a syntax error. How many clients can run this method?

Comment: That's hideously involved because you have to (essentially) parse an arbitrary expression, which is much more difficult than just escaping values. It's fairly easy to establish if the resulting statement is at least one single statement, but that's not full protection against SQL injection either because it can still select arbitrary tables and columns (including system tables, user accounts, etc.) First, try *very* hard to restrict the input in ways that aren't vulnerable. In particular, how are users *actually* using the `WHERE`? What tables are they *actually* accessing?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the prompt responses. @MarcGravell indeed I am parsing those values, which is way easier task than the one about the where statements.

Comment: [Here's how django does it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/where.py).

Comment: @Adelin but that's accepting some kind of expression tree as the input - a very different scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `where` clause is currently based on being a pre-composed `string`, then frankly I don't think it is a viable approach to attempt to "secure" it. It is theoretically possible, but any attempt at parsing the SQL will fail if the composed and compromised (injected) `where` clause is legitimate (but abusive). At that point: you've *already lost track* of the original intent. That's kinda the entire point of SQL injection: the resultant SQL *is valid SQL* - so it is very hard for you to tell the difference between `where Name = 'Fred Orson' -- check name` (probably fine) and `where Name = 'Fred' Or 1=1 --'` (injected - query widening).

So: while I acknowledge that you say:

> changing the function signature and the way the clients use it is just not feasible.

*Not* changing the function signature doesn't really help you solve the problem. Trying to detect certain patterns is just an arms race, where you need to win every time and the attacker needs to win only once.

If it was me, I'd be doing something like:

```
[Obsolete("Please specify parameters separately - use 'null' if no parameters are needed")]
SomeFunction(string table, string column, string where) {
    return SomeFunction(table, column, where, null);
}
SomeFunction(string table, string column, string where, object args) {
    // ...
}
```

and using an approach like "Dapper" uses to compose the parameters from the `args` parameter - or just use "Dapper" itself to run the query, and use that functionality for free.

This approach:

- prevents new uses of the dangerous API being added
- lets the existing code continue to work for now
- but lets you track how many outstanding problem calls there are, by watching the warnings

---

Edit: note: the ***point*** of the `args` parameter is to allow the caller to *parameterize* their inputs, i.e.

```
string name = ...
var users = SomeFunction("Users", "Id", "Name=@name", new { name });
```

With `SomeFunction` decomposing `args` and adding parameter name/value pairs from the properties on `args` (if it is non-null). There are various approaches to composing parameter sets, but the approach shown here is simple and easy to implement correctly - which makes it a clear win for me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled it can be **parameterized**, though; I'll make that more explicit

Comment: Yes, it **can** be parameterized, but **must** it be?

Comment: @ZoharPeled if you want your system to be secure, then: **yes**.  Parameterization solves a wide range of other problems in addition to security, of course, which make it worthwhile *even without* the security aspect. If you're saying "but someone can just pass the injected version and pass `null` as the arg" - they yes: no amount of code can prevent against stupid. At that point, that's a failure of the development and review process.

Comment: I'm well aware of the benefits of parameterized queries, that's not what I'm asking. What I'm asking is what prevents a user to do this: `var users = SomeFunction("Users", "Id", "Name='name' or 1=1")`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I edited my comment to address that, as I realized what you mean; read from "If you're saying..."

Comment: Nice answer, this seems the go-to way in this situation... I have one question: How could I know from code that the argument name is actually passed as parametrized in @name? I mean, how do I correlate the @name with the arg name? so I can go sql['name'] = arg.value (something like this) -- I guess I will have to parse the parameters by splitting the string or something?

Comment: @dasjkdj theoretically you *don't even need to* - you could just add everything you find on `args`; but this could lead to more values being sent than are needed. The way "Dapper" does this is simply to check - for every key `foo` found on `args`, does the query contain any of `@foo`, `:foo` or `?foo` ? - see https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L2231 - if yes: it adds it; if not: it doesn't. Seriously, it may be possible to simply get "Dapper" to do all the work here.

Comment: "no amount of code can prevent against stupid." - That's why my stackoverflow profile has that Rick Cook quote - Indeed, the Universe **is** winning. :-)